# trigonometry (oblique triangle)

Tags: trigonometry

A surveyor wants to find the distance from point A on one side of a small lake from a vantage point C he measures two distances AC=325m and BC=235m. He also measures the angle between AC and BC to be 52'40'. What is the distance from A to B?

Comment: please add your ideas/work and where you struck.

Answer (score 2):

So, $\angle ACB=52'40''$

Applying the [Law of Cosine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html)s,
$$\cos 52'40''=\frac{AC^2+BC^2-AB^2}{2\cdot AC\cdot BC}\iff AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-2\cdot AC\cdot BC\cdot \cos 52'40''$$

Comment: so how can i draw a diagam from that problem...pls...answer

Comment: oh i cant get it...the problem is the surveyor will try to find angle AC do you mean i will draw a lake that would  create a oblique...thank you..

Comment: @yoj, we have two options : (1)Draw $52′40′′$ which can not be  ruler-and-compass construction, make its container sides AC=325 & BC=235 unit. Join AB.  (2) Once you have side $|AB|$ known, its not tough to draw a triangle with all the three sides known.